# Showing p-values in scientific notation with rcorr() function

Tags: r, regression-testing

I have a correlation matrix that I am trying to test the p-values for using [rcorr()](http://127.0.0.1:14205/library/Hmisc/html/rcorr.html) to get a correlation matrix. This is found in the `Hmisc` package. I have a matrix which you can see here called `KCN` which you can see the top 6 records of here:
0   0       0             0        1              0
0   0       0             0        1              0
0   0       1             0        2              0
2   1       5             3        5              0
0   0       1             0        0              0
0   2       1             0        2              0

Then I run rcorr:

```
rKCR<-rcorr(as.matrix(KCN[,2:7]),type="pearson")
```

If I then call rKCR, I keep getting all 0s for the p-valued matrix and I figure these are very weak correlations that are being rounded. I ran the corr.test() function as seen here on 2 columns of KCN:

```
cor.test(KCN[,2],KCN[,3],type="pearson")
```

I got a p-value of 2.2e-16 which is obviously very small. I used the entire dataframe in the rcorr() function, and after looking at the documentation am wondering if there is any way at all to get a p-value matrix represented in scientific notation? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `m = rcorr(as.matrix(mtcars))$P; m` prints in scientific notation for me.

Comment: I tried that using what I have:
m=rcorr(as.matrix(KCN[,2:7]))$P
and I got this:
NA   0       0             0        0              0
All                      0  NA       0             0        0              0
Climate                  0   0      NA             0        0              0
Fish.Wildlife            0   0       0            NA        0              0
Land.use                 0   0       0             0       NA              0
Transportation           0   0       0             0        0             NA

Comment: You should edit your question to include a reproducible example. Right now, the eye is drawn to the formatted code block that uses `cor.test`, which is only a little relevant. You should mention the package that `rcorr` is in and provide a little bit of data (simulated is fine) that shows your problem - my sample data doesn't show your problem (please verify that my sample data also works for you), but my sample data has p-values on the order of 1e-6, not 1e-16.

Comment: I tried to add the tables, but I keep getting an obnoxious message indicating that with the table my text "appears as code' which is very user unfriendly, like most of Stack Exchange's forum. So you can only see the 6 first records with the "head" function above. You can now see the package which I didn't initially place.

Comment: Just paste in `dput(head(KCN))` and format it as code. As far as "I keep getting all 0s for the p-valued matrix and I figure these are very weak correlations that are being rounded", you should figure those are very *strong* correlations that are being rounded. Weak correlations would have p values far from 0, not close to 0.

Comment: I also tried the function with mtcars and I ran a typeof() function on it and noticed it was a list. The other day when I tried running correlations I got errors when the columns weren't numeric, so I converted them into "double". Shouldn't the as.matrix() function work regardless to take care of this?

Comment: I also tried to convert it back with as.list() and because I am only asking for the last 6 columns, getting dimension errors. I also converted to a matrix and get subscript out of bounds....please advise

Comment: Data frames are lists - but special lists with additional properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
k <- cor.test(KCN[,2],KCN[,3],type="pearson")
pVal <- k$p.value
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that wasn't what I was trying to do. See the rcorr() function provides an entire matrix with all of the correlation matches, and then another matrix of p-values. I was able to get what you have here, but what I wanted was a matrix of p-values for all of KCN thrown into rcorr()

Comment: it would help greatly to create a reproducible example with `dput(head(matrix))`

Comment: I am confused by what you are expecting to see there. When I ran that, I got this: c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)
Is that helpful?